# Delphi: Is it ok for a form to free it self?

Tags: delphi, self-destruction

I have a form that I use to show some information for some seconds. Is it ok for the form to free itself?  Can I start a timer in the constructor, and then call self.free in the timer-event? Or will this potentially lead to trouble?

Comment: According to the manual, inside of event handlers, you MUST call Release instead of Close or Free. 
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Release

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In addition, with a form you can call `Release`.

It sends a CM_RELEASE message to the form. As a reaction it calls Free.
The advantage of release is that there are no messages left for the form which could result in a crash.

Comment: I think I will go for this one, in combination with setting the owner as a extra insurance.

Comment: @Rigel, not exactly, Close uses CloseQuery which can be used to interrupt the process and it is not guaranteed to free the form. Depending on the cloise action, the form can also hide or minimize (Have a look at TCustomForm.Close  in Vcl.Forms.pas.

Comment: Yes. Of course. `Close` will or will not close the form, depending on how you set the close action. But I was speaking about something else: (if it set to caFree) `.Close` is as safe as `.Release`. I mean it will not create the problems that `.Free` will create.

Answer (score 18):

You can make the form to free itself when it gets closed by the user or from code:

```
procedure TForm27.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TForm27.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm27.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Close;
end;
```

Make sure you supply an owner in the constructor incase the application shutdowns and the form is not destroyed at the time. The owner will free the form before freeing itself.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like the TCloseAction-idea. Maybe I should use that instead of release...

Comment: if only forms had DefaultCloseAction properties, so pone could auto-free them without assigning event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a whole suite of objects that free themselves, and I've run various tests on them with no problems/leaks shown. A TForm might be more complex, but as long as Self.Free() is the last call made, you ought to be safe.

(For those wondering why on earth I have object that free themselves; I pass them around the system a lot, so I implemented by own reference counting scheme. When the last reference is released, so the object frees itself).

Comment: But Self.Free would almost *never* be the last call made by a form because a form is almost always running code in reaction to some user action. Use Release instead.

Comment: Why not just use Interfaces for reference-counting?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what is done with Interfaces.

Comment: Yes, but you should remember that Delphi's TComponent overrides the interface's reference counting, which often causes confusion.

Comment: Using interfaces, the form would be freed when it goes out of scoop. I don't want that. I want it to live as long as it wants without any references to it, and then free it self when its done showing it self.

Comment: Fabio: I'm sure you could override that.
Vegar: Interfaces are reference counted, not scope-managed.

Comment: Yes, but as long as you don't keep a reference, wouldn't the referencecount go to zero when the code where you created the form goes out of scope?

Comment: Only if you never pass it to something else...  When you create the object, the ref gets incremented, so it is 1.  When you assign it to something else, it becomes incremented again, so it is 2. When it leaves scope, it gets decremented, to ONE, and thus isn't destroyed.